# array_chunk reseting id in each array position

Tags: php

I created a array which stores XML elements in it.

```
$itemArray = array();
$itemArray[] = array ('[{id:'.$item.'species:'.$gender.'}]');
```

Now I used array_chunk to split the Array in 3 item parts.

```
$arrayChunked = array_chunk($itemArray, 3, true);
```

If I use:

```
var_dump($arrayChunked);
```

then the stored Items look like this:

```
0 => array(0,1,2)
1 => array(3,4,5)
2 => array(6,7,8)
```

But i need them stored like:

```
0 => array(0,1,2)
1 => array(0,1,2)
2 => array(0,1,2)
```

Any Idea of how i could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop passing "true" as the third argument; you're telling it to preserve the original keys.  If you take that out, it will reindex it automatically (as noted in the [array_chunk docs](http://php.net/array_chunk)).

i.e.

```
$arrayChunked = array_chunk($itemArray, 3);
```